# Stock/Futures put options

Tags: finance

How do you find out how much a put contract would cost?

Example:

> The premium for a 99.00 Eurodollar futures put option is 0.55 and the
>   spot price is 98.51

So I have the intrinsic value which is `$1225`, but I am not sure how to compute the time value and how much that put contract would cost. Still trying to understand options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping your example, for a *European* put option on a future contract you can apply the formula known as [*Black -76*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_model). For *American* or *Bermudan* options on futures this Black -76 is also adequate because if you exercise early than you would stand with the future which is delivered at expiry anyway - of course the difference is that it might be easier to sell the future..

Comment: Yea i got it now. I know you could use black-scholes, but i was just using a simple equation where Call option = Intrinsic Value - Time value. But i got it know. For some reason my calculation kept coming out wrong, probably a 0 or something, but when i walked away and tried it later i got it. *shrugs* Thanks though.

Comment: The formula known as Black and Scholes is not the same as Black -76. Basically BS is for European stock options while B76 is for future contracts (also known as bond options).